# how can I change this quicksort code into 3 different parts that I want to?

Tags: c, linked-list, quicksort

For my assignment, my code must have 3 source files:

main.c (Handles input and output, as well as top-level program logic.)
node.h (Declares the data structure and function quicksort, which sorts a given doubly linked list with the ascending order), and printlist, which prints a linked list to the screen.
node.c (Defines the function quicksort and printlist, as declared in node.h.)

The main function must use scanf function call to read the input data from keybord (note that the input redirection can be used to directly read the data from a data file). The number of data (in the data file) is not pre-determined.

this is the code that my instructor gave me. I'm really confused, do I need to break the code into 3 parts, if so how?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void qsort(int a[10], int first, int last);
int main() {

    int i, n, a[10], j, pivot, last, t;
    printf("enter the no of elements\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("enter the elements\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    qsort(a, 0, n - 1);
    printf("sorted elements is\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("\n%d", a[i]);

}

void qsort(int a[10], int first, int last) {
    int i, j, t, pivot, n;
    if (first < last) {
        i = first;
        j = last;
        pivot = first;
        while (i < j) {
            while (a[i] <= a[pivot] && i < last)
                i++;
            while (a[j] > a[pivot])
                j--;
            if (i < j) {
                t = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = t;
            }
        }

        t = a[pivot];
        a[pivot] = a[j];
        a[j] = t;
        qsort(a, first, j - 1);
        qsort(a, j + 1, last);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your instructor gave you a qsort that sorts an array, she expects you to implement it on linked lists. Maybe that's just an example of how quicksort works?

Anyway, you will probably need to copy that main into a main.c file. That file will need to include node.h. Inside of it you will declare the list structures, a way to create them, quicksort and a function that prints the list on screen. Inside o node.c you will implement everything you declared on node.h.

You should use the defined qsort only as a reference and you probably need to make changes to main so it creates a list you coded instead of an array.

That's what I make of your assignment, but you should probably clear things up with your instructor.

Comment: so what should I put into node.c? I'm so confused?

Comment: You probably want the implementation of the list, quicksort and printlist in there.